# Is there a way to highlight(bold) something inside the code block?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Today I asked a question where i was trying to make some text bold inside the code. But i'm not able to do it.I thought it will be more convenient for the users to read.
[My Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31470243/how-to-do-the-mutiple-insert-into-select-query-in-a-single-insert-statement) . For Example, in the below statement i was trying to Make `columnB` as `BOLD`. Instead it is coming with `**`. This is small query, so it doesn't matter much but when we are seeing a very big query i guess it might be useful atleast for few.

```
Select ColumnA,**ColumnB**,ColumnC from Mytable;
```

I may not be aware . Please let me know about the option. Thanks.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32705/bold-code-in-a-question

Comment: Quick answer: Nope.

Comment: @Cerbrus Long answer, sure, but you don't *really* want to go there.

Comment: @Cerbrus There is a simple way of doing it.